# pass a string to a hidden field in rails simple form

Tags: simple-form

I am trying to build a simple message relay system from scratch. My form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.input :content, label: "Your message" %>
<%= f.input :target_user_id, label: "Who are you sending your message to?"  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'sender_email', current_user.email %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to pass "current_user.email" to the message model, where "Message.sender_email" is a string, but I am getting "nil" when I look at the created Message in the console. All the other fields do get passed though.

Comment: I actually found a better way of dealing with this issue. I just wrote added a line to the messages controller update action which passes the email into the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your controller:

```
@message.sender_email = @user.email
```

in the message create method.